# Import term set with Navigation Node Appearance

Tags: sharepoint-online, out-of-the-box

I need to add term using OutOfBox "Import Term Set" using CSV option in SharePoint o365.

I need to set "Simple Link or Header" property url value.

What is the column name should give in Excel/CSV file?

I need to use OutOfBox only. Or anyway is possible using JSOM?